# How to use Jacoco plugin along with JVM test suites plugin in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

We have a java project which is using gradle build tool. We are using jacoco plugin to generate test coverage report. Later we have added test suites using JVM Test Suite plugin of gradle. We have observed that all those test classes run by test suites are not getting covered in code coverage report of jacoco. So If anyone got some idea what exactly should i write in build.gradle file for accomplish this, that would be great. Thanks.

This is the build.gradle file snippet:-

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'jvm-test-suite'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

testing {
    suites {
        test {
            useJUnitJupiter()
        }

        customTest(JvmTestSuite) {
            dependencies {
                ... // some dependencies
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.named('check') {
    dependsOn(testing.suites.customTest)
}

dependencies {
... // some other dependencies
}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test
    reports {
        xml.required = true
    }
}
```

Comment: try `customTest.jacoco.enabled = true`

Answer (score 3):

See the new [JaCoCo Report Aggregation Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_report_aggregation_plugin.html) and the [aggregation related Samples](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/) (under the Java heading) for information on how to consolidate coverage across multiple test suites.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that you've defined an additional test suite (`integrationTest`) and added jacoco plugin as follows:

```kotlin
plugins {
    java
    `jvm-test-suite`
    jacoco
}

testing {
    suites {
        @Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
        named<JvmTestSuite>("test") {
        useJUnitJupiter()
            testType.set(TestSuiteType.UNIT_TEST)
        }

        @Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
        register<JvmTestSuite>("integrationTest") {
            useJUnitJupiter()
            testType.set(TestSuiteType.INTEGRATION_TEST)

            dependencies {
                configurations.named("integrationTestImplementation") {
                    extendsFrom(configurations.testImplementation.get())
                }
                implementation(project())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

each time you execute either `test` or `integrationTest` there is a corresponding jacoco exec file created at `build/(test|integrationTest).exec`

Now to get html-reports (or xml/csv-reports, depending on which one you've requested in `tasks.jacocoTestReport {...}` block), `jacoco` plugin adds `jacocoTestReport` task which transforms `.exec` file into other formats. The `jacocoTestReport` assumes that there is only one default test suite called `test` and thus only respects `build/jacoco/test.exec`.

As for now (Gradle 8.1.1), adding the [`jacoco-report-aggregation` plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/userguide/jacoco_report_aggregation_plugin.html) to the build will automatically create corresponding task to convert `.exec` coverage data into other formats for any additional test suite you declare. In my example, after applying `id("jacoco-report-aggregation")`, I will automatically get `integrationTestCodeCoverageReport` task which will take care of transforming `build/jacoco/integrationTest.exec` into html and/or other formats.

Finally, if I want to have a single aggregated coverage report in html format, I need to use the `testCodeCoverageReport` task, which was also brought by introducing `jacoco-report-aggregation` to the build. Based on the description ("Generates **aggregated** code coverage report") the goal of this task is exactly report aggregation. But you need to adjust it's configuration before using, so it becomes aware of your custom test suite:

```kotlin
reporting {
    reports {
        @Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
        named<JacocoCoverageReport>("testCodeCoverageReport") {
            reportTask {
                executionData.builtBy(tasks.test, tasks.named("integrationTest")) // adding dependencies between aggregate reporting and test tasks
                executionData.from( // specifying paths to process coverage in .exec format
                    project.layout.buildDirectory.file("jacoco/test.exec"),
                    project.layout.buildDirectory.file("jacoco/integrationTest.exec")
                )
            }
            testType.set("Aggregate")
        }
    }
}
```

Now to get a single aggregated coverage report in html, execute `./gadlew test integrationTest testCodeCoverageReport`

---

UPD 2023-06-30

As for Gradle 8.1 [here](https://github.com/jjohannes/understanding-gradle/blob/e3ef31d728e6d13fb08a58984e9af546d2c90340/21_Test_and_Code_Coverage_Reporting/my-build-logic/java-plugins/src/main/kotlin/my-java-application.gradle.kts#L10C1-L21) is the universal way to aggregate INTEGRATION_TEST coverage data in addition to UNIT_TEST coverage (without hard-coding paths to `.exec` files) and to produce a single report as a result:

```kotlin
reporting {
    reports {
        @Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
        create<JacocoCoverageReport>("testCodeCoverageReportRoot") {
            testType.set(TestSuiteType.UNIT_TEST)
            reportTask {
                executionData.from(
                    configurations["aggregateCodeCoverageReportResults"]
                        .incoming.artifactView {
                            lenient(true)
                            withVariantReselection()
                            attributes {
                                attribute(Category.CATEGORY_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(Category.VERIFICATION))
                                attribute(TestSuiteType.TEST_SUITE_TYPE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(TestSuiteType.INTEGRATION_TEST))
                                attribute(VerificationType.VERIFICATION_TYPE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(VerificationType.JACOCO_RESULTS))
                                attribute(ArtifactTypeDefinition.ARTIFACT_TYPE_ATTRIBUTE, ArtifactTypeDefinition.BINARY_DATA_TYPE)
                            }
                        }.files,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you perform coverage aggregation in a separate module, do not forget to add your source/test code modules as a dependencies with `jacocoAggregation` scope, like this:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    jacocoAggregation(project(":my-domain-model-with-unit-tests-only"))
    jacocoAggregation(project(":spring-boot-app-with-unit-and-integration-tests"))
}
```

Many thanks to Jendrik Johannes for [his youtube video series "Understanding Gradle"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZvzWlP9BYE) and [his great accompanied examples on GitHub](https://github.com/jjohannes/understanding-gradle/tree/main/21_Test_and_Code_Coverage_Reporting)